# How will the Buddhists, Hindus, Jains, Sikhs, etc come to recognize the G-d of Israel when the Messiah comes

Tags: gentiles, theology, messianic-redemption

How will the Buddhists, Hindus, Jains, Sikhs, etc come to recognize the G-d of Israel when the Messiah comes since these religions and rest of the 49% of the world's population that doesn't believe that the Torah Is the divinely inspired word of G-d and that the Torah was given to the Children Of Israel at the foot of Mt. Sinai by G-d himself?

Answer (score 7):

Rambam in Hilchos Melachim 11:4 writes:

> אך מחשבות בורא עולם אין כוח באדם להשיגם כי לא דרכינו דרכיו ולא
>   מחשבותינו מחשבותיו וכל הדברים האלו של ישוע הנצרי ושל זה הישמעאלי שעמד
>   אחריו אינן אלא לישר דרך למלך המשיח ולתקן העולם כולו לעבוד את ה' ביחד
>   שנאמר כי אז אהפוך אל אחד עמים שפה ברורה לקרוא כולם בשם ה' לעבדו שכם
>   אחד. כיצד כבר נתמלא העולם מדברי המשיח ומדברי התורה ומדברי המצוות ופשטו
>   דברים אלו באיים רחוקים ובעמים רבים ערלי לב והם נושאים ונותנים בדברים
>   אלו ובמצוות התורה אלו אומרים מצוות אלו אמת היו וכבר בטלו בזמן הזה ולא
>   היו נוהגות לדורות ואלו אומרים דברים נסתרים יש בהן ואינן כפשוטן וכבר בא
>   משיח וגילה נסתריהם וכשיעמוד המלך המשיח באמת ויצליח וירום וינשא מיד הם
>   כולם חוזרים ויודעים ששקר נחלו אבותיהם ושנביאיהם ואבותיהם הטעום
>
> Nevertheless, the intent of the Creator of the world is not within the
>   power of man to comprehend, for His ways are not our ways, nor are His
>   thoughts, our thoughts. Ultimately, all the deeds of Jesus of Nazareth
>   and that Ishmaelite who arose after him will only serve to prepare the
>   way for Mashiach's coming and the improvement of the entire world,
>   motivating the nations to serve God together as Tzephaniah 3:9 states:
>   'I will transform the peoples to a purer language that they all will
>   call upon the name of God and serve Him with one purpose.'
>
> How will this come about? The entire world has already become filled
>   with the mention of Mashiach, Torah, and mitzvot. These matters have
>   been spread to the furthermost islands to many stubborn-hearted
>   nations. They discuss these matters and the mitzvot of the Torah,
>   saying: 'These mitzvot were true, but were already negated in the
>   present age and are not applicable for all time.'
>
> Others say: 'Implied in the mitzvot are hidden concepts that can not
>   be understood simply. The Mashiach has already come and revealed those
>   hidden truths.'
>
> When the true Messianic king will arise and prove successful, his
>   position becoming exalted and uplifted, they will all return and
>   realize that their ancestors endowed them with a false heritage and
>   their prophets and ancestors caused them to err.
>
> ([Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188356/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-11.htm))

Comment: "...that Ishmaelite" meaning Muhammad.