# Can a Jew encourage non-Jews to convert to other monotheistic religions?

Tags: gentiles, avodah-zarah, chinuch-education

Would it be permissible for a Jew to encourage or help a non-Jew convert from a faith that involves avodah zara to one that does not? For example a Christian (on the notion that Christianity is avodah Zara) can become converted to Islam (monotheism without avodah Zara). Additionally, would it be prohibited to spread the teachings of another religion to non-Jews based upon this notion of going from avodah Zara to monotheism?

Comment: Maybe "encourage to convert"? I don't think there are very many Jewish imams out there waiting to convert Xtians to Islam, and those who are out there presumably care very little about whether it's halachically permitted to do so (since they themselves have severely transgressed halacha first by converting to Islam and then by becoming Muslim religious leaders)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89583/13438