# Does the Torah encourage monotheistic evangelism?

Tags: avodah-zarah, christianity, kiruv-outreach

Although Judaism is not a proselytizing religion in the classical sense, is there any responsibility to bring non-jews to monotheism and away from idolatry?

Comment: My question nothing to do with the truth of judaism just monotheism

Comment: Jews don't proselytize. It is always imperative to share the truth with Jews first. If you're on a bus and there is a secular Jew and a non-Jews, always teach the Jew first. It is your responsibility to bring as many Jews as you can to the Torah. It is a mitzvah. As for non-Jews, they come second. Rambam actually says it is permitted to teach non-Jews, but they should not read the Torah, it can damage them spiritually. They must stay away from the Talmud and only follow the 7 mitzvot.

Comment: This is the classical way. Basically, Jews would have been more concerned for non-Jews had they not been persecuted by them for two millennia.

Comment: @BigMouth If I’m understanding your question and comment correctly, is https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105385/ a better question to mark this as a duplicate of?

Comment: @DonielF I was thinking more to dissuade Non-jews from idolatrous worship (christianity possibly), not necessarily to adopt a different belief system.

Comment: Why is this closed as a duplicate!?! This question has nothing to do with "the truth of judaism" . The duplicate Nazis are back at it again!